# Spring-boot running under istio sidecar proxy throw HTTP 403 Error

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-sidecar

There are ServiceA and ServiceB services deployed under the same namespace. There is istio enabled for validating request authentication. Any calls to the service needs to have 'Authrization' header with valid jwt token. It get validated with [RequestAuthenication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/) along with [AuthorizationPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) set. It is working as expected and I can make http calls with valid auth token. Now the ServiceA needs to talk to ServiceB. I used the service-name `serviceb..<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`. The call is passed to ServiceB but fails with HTTP 403. It is expecting the auth token header.
How can I allow the calls between the services within the same namespace without auth token?
I am trying to find an example to customize the [AuthorizationPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/), so that it allows the calls with in the same namespace as trusted service without auth token. Please let me know, whether it is possible or if there an alternate way.

All my pods running under services are spring-boot and using RestTemplate for calling between services.

Below is the istio auth policy used

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: service-auth-policy
  namespace: namespace-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
      - source:
          requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

Comment: Below is the istio auth policy used..(I tried using code format but below is wrapped in lines)
`
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: service-auth-policy
  namespace: namkespace-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
      - source:
          requestPrincipals: ["*"]
`

Comment: It would be better to include that code in your question, and not as a comment

Comment: @user140547 I want to edit and add it to the question. I could not find a way to edit it and so put it in the comment.

Comment: Well there should be an edit link at the bottom of your question

Comment: @user140547 thanks for pointing it out. I was trying to find a way to edit and read somewhere, to edit a question/answer depends on the user's profile history. I  misunderstood  and did not see the edit button right below. I added the comment to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the original authorization policy from

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: service-auth-policy
  namespace: namespace-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
      - source:
          requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

including the namespace as below

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: catalog-auth-policy
  namespace: namespace-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
      - source:
          requestPrincipals: ["*"]
      - source:
          namespaces: ["namespace-dev"]
```

and it worked as expected.